# Backend API Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, backend

While implementing backend API to use backend services, I have done code as below:

timezone_service.py:

```
class TaskQueueTimeZoneHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        outdict=self.request.params
        logging.info("Enter In taskqueue")        
        taskqueue.add(url='/api/timezone/setTimeZone',target='timezonebackend')        
        logging.info("Out Of taskqueue")
```

While call /api/timezone/setTimezone if i am using any function or file of main application it gives undefined because its create seprate version for named we given in backends.yaml (I want to used file from my main application py folder)

```
backends:
- name: timezonebackend
class: B4
instances: 1
options: dynamic
start: gapi/timezone_service.py
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a question about backends.

In any Python code, if you want to use a function or variable defined in another file, you need to import it first.

Comment: it is not thing to import only, you are not understand my question, the file I want to use is in my main application and as backend create seprate version when i am trying to import it its give undefined error and reason behind it version of both  backend and main application is different. So Its question about backend.